# What is the probabillity of winning at ball drawing?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If balls are numerated 1 to 48, and 35 balls are drawn, what is the chance we have 6 numbers ? Order of balls is not important.

It's local bingo and I was wondering what are the chance of winning.

Comment: Do you mean six particular numbers?

Comment: I mean any of 6 balls of 36 drawn in interval [1, 48] .

Comment: With or without replacing?

Comment: @dhrab: Apparently it is bingo, so without replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${48 \choose 35}$ equally likely sets of $35$ selected numbers

Of these, ${48-6 \choose 35-6}$ contain all six desired numbers

So the chance that all six desired numbers are selected in the $35$ is $\dfrac{42 \choose 29}{48 \choose 35}\approx 0.13227$

Comment: Is it 13 % or 0.13 % ? I didn't get the last part

Comment: @DinkoPehar $13\%$  or $\frac{18445}{139449}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Probably to be solved with hypergeometric distribution.

Turn things around and select randomly $6$ distinct numbers.

Then what is the probability that all $6$ numbers do not exceed $35$?

(on how many ways can you select $6$ numbers in $[1,35]$ and on how many ways can you select $6$ numbers in $[1,48]$?)